# SRVE0278E: Error while adding servlet mapping --> /*

Tags: spring, websphere

I am trying to deploy my application on a local Websphere Application Server (Version "8.5.5.9") with Java 8

I always get this error:

```
[1/16/19 14:40:21:530 GMT] 000000c3 webapp        I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp log SRVE0292I: Servlet Message - [adminART_war#adminART.war]:.Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'adr' 
[1/16/19 14:40:21:783 GMT] 000000c3 SystemOut     O INFO  SecurityNamespaceHandler --       --       --Spring Security 'config' module version is 4.0.1.RELEASE 
[1/16/19 14:40:30:424 GMT] 000000c3 SystemOut     O INFO  GlobalMethodSecurityBeanDefinitionParser --       --       --Expressions were enabled for method security but no SecurityExpressionHandler was configured. All hasPermision() expressions will evaluate to false. 
[1/16/19 14:41:42:690 GMT] 000000c3 ServletWrappe I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: [adminART_war] [/ArtOSAdmin] [adr]: Initialization successful. 
[1/16/19 14:41:42:691 GMT] 000000c3 webapp        W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp initializeStaticFileHandler SRVE0278E: Error while adding servlet mapping --> /*. 
[1/16/19 14:41:42:697 GMT] 000000c3 webapp        I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp log SRVE0292I: Servlet Message - [adminART_war#adminART.war]:.Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'adr' 
[1/16/19 14:41:42:721 GMT] 000000c3 ServletWrappe I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper doDestroy SRVE0253I: [adminART_war] [/ArtOSAdmin] [adr]: Destroy successful. 
[1/16/19 14:41:42:724 GMT] 000000c3 webapp        I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp log SRVE0292I: Servlet Message - [adminART_war#adminART.war]:.Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext 
[1/16/19 14:42:02:997 GMT] 000000c3 SystemOut     O INFO  EhCacheManagerFactoryBean --       --       --Shutting down EhCache CacheManager 
[1/16/19 14:42:03:060 GMT] 000000c3 SystemOut     O INFO  LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean --       --       --Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default' 
[1/16/19 14:42:03:066 GMT] 000000c3 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl WebGroup SRVE0015E: Failure to initialize Web application adr Banque 
[1/16/19 14:42:03:071 GMT] 000000c3 DeployedAppli W   WSVR0206E: Module, adminART.war, of application, adminART_war.ear/deployments/adminART_war, failed to start
```

I've configured the file ibm-web-ext.xml under WEB-INF as described on some supports like that:

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
    <web-ext
        xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-web-ext_1_0.xsd"
        version="1.0">
        <default-error-page uri="error.jsp"/>
        <jsp-attribute name="useThreadTagPool" value="true" />
        <jsp-attribute name="verbose" value="false" />
        <jsp-attribute name="deprecation" value="false" />
        <jsp-attribute name="reloadEnabled" value="true" />
        <jsp-attribute name="reloadInterval" value="5" />
        <jsp-attribute name="keepgenerated"  value="true" />
        <jsp-attribute name="trackDependencies" value="true" />
        <reload-interval value="9"/>
        <auto-encode-requests value="true"/>
        <auto-encode-responses value="false"/>
        <enable-directory-browsing value="false"/>
        <enable-file-serving value="false"/>
        <pre-compile-jsps value="false"/>
        <enable-reloading value="true"/>
        <enable-serving-servlets-by-class-name value="true"/>
    </web-ext>
```

This the mapping on my web.xml:

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<!-- Spring MVC -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>adr</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>adr</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please add the complete stacktrace

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this error, and at the corresponding code in WebApp, can you look see if there was an FFDC log produced at the same time as this warning?  If I've found the correct code, there should be an FFDC which was also produced, and that would have additional details as to the exact error which occurred.

> [1/16/19 14:41:42:691 GMT] 000000c3 webapp        W
>       com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp initializeStaticFileHandler
>       SRVE0278E: Error while adding servlet mapping --> /*.

Answer (score 0):

By default WebSphere will install a DefaultApplication EAR that will use the / context root. If you want to use this context root, you will next to remove the DefaultApplication from the server or change the context root for this application to something else.